# How to get whatsapp icon in html emailer?

Tags: html, icons, whatsapp

I tried this code. It's showing me the icon in the code whenever I'm sending html emailer which I have already created. But when the email has been sent, the icon disappears and a spacing is showing in that particular area. How to fix it?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">`

`<i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-1x" style="color:green"></i>`

Answer (score 1):

> Refer This

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>fa fa-whatsapp</h1>

<i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="font-size:24px"></i>
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="font-size:36px"></i>
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="font-size:48px;color:Green"></i>
<br>

<p>Used on a button:</p>
<button style="font-size:24px">Button <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></button>

<p>Unicode:</p>
<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf232;</i>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to possible security problems, Email service providers won't permits yet. You can't use a third parties source in your mail (SWF/JS/CSS and any dynamic files).

SVG image are partially accepted but you can use a authorized image type (png/gif/jpg) or try to generate somethings like as with HTML :

```html
<span style="color: darkgreen;font-weight: bold;">&#9990</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still the same. No change. I can see the icon when I'm adding the code though. But when the email is sent, there's no icon in that designated area.